# jQuery 3.2.1 and TypeScript promises

Tags: jquery, typescript, ecmascript-6, promise

I am using TypeScript 2.4 with jQuery 3.2.1 and the latest type definitions.

In one service class I have this method:

```
DoSearch(searchItem: string): Promise < IWikipediaRestRecord[] > {
    return $.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&callback=?&search=" + searchItem)
      .then(function(data) {
        var result: IWikipediaRestRecord[] = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++) {
          result.push({
            title: data[1][i],
            content: data[2][i],
            link: data[3][i]
          });
        }
        return result;
      });
```

Compiling the project, I get the following error:

```
error TS2322: Type '**Promise3**<IWikipediaRestRecord[], any, never, never, never, never, never, never, never>' is not assignable to type '**Promise**<IWikipediaRestRecord[]>'.
  Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
    Type '{ <ARD = never, AJD = never, AND = never, BRD = never, BJD = never, BND = never, CRD = never, CJD...' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = IWikipediaRestRecord[], TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: IWikipediaRestRecord...'.
```

I think that the problem can be of different type promises.
I am using ES5 compilation and including in my tsconfig.json the following lib: "dom", "es5", "es2015.iterable".

Any idea how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably best to pick which promise implementation you actually want to use. The native implementation is probably the better choice, so you can do just that

```
var jqPromise = $.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&callback=?&search=" + searchItem)
  .then(function(data) {
    var result: IWikipediaRestRecord[] = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data[1].length; i++) {
      result.push({
        title: data[1][i],
        content: data[2][i],
        link: data[3][i]
      });
    }
    return result;
  });

return Promise.resolve(jqPromise);
```

where that final line will convert the jQuery promise object into a standard ES6 promise.